# IBM Watson Discovery: Reusing data from a collection on Python

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-discovery

We need to reuse a Watson Discovery collection in another project programmatically. I inspect the request on the web version and seeing that it sends an object having `"dataset_id"`:

```
{
  "dataset_id": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx",
  "name": "PDFs",
  "language": "en",
  "projectType": "document_retrieval"
}
```

to `https://us-south.discovery.watson.cloud.ibm.com/v2/api/instances/crn%3Av1%3Abluemix%3Apublic%3Adiscovery%3Aus-south%3Aa%{instance_id or something like that}1%3A%3A/v2/projects/{project_id}/collections`

I tried to push the same data object using a modified [create_collection](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/ibm_watson/discovery_v2.py#L124) but Discovery only creates a collection ignoring the dataset_id. Here's the output calling the modified create_collection:

```
url:  /v2/projects/{project_id}/collections
result:  {'name': 'PDFs', 'collection_id': 'xxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx', 'description': '', 'created': '2022-03-18T03:16:54.565Z', 'language': 'en', 'enrichments': []}
```

My question is whether it's possible to reuse collections programmatically? Am I missing something? What should I do in this case?

We need to do this in order to evaluate the discovery project' performance.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot reuse a collection because it is the resource managed by a Discovery instance. You can reuse a data source. The API docs for Watson Discovery do not show any reuse options for collections. You create, update, delete them. https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/discovery-data#introduction

Comment: Thank you. There's actually an option to reuse a collection. I'm just not sure if the 2 projects have to be on the same instance or not. But yeah, I'm totally convinced that we can't do that with the sdk.
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/discovery-data?topic=discovery-data-manage-collections#manage-collections-reuse